# How can I access a globally defined property that is accessed through a property file using Spock when unit testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm Trying to unit test a method for which uses a globally defined variable derived from a property file using @Value Annotation. How can I access this global property in a service class in the unit testing without having to pass it to the method signature.

ex:
Spring Boot service named 'SampleService'

```
@Value("${sampleproperty.value}")
private String sampleProperty;

private sampleMethodName(){
     //method which uses the global variable 'sampleProperty'
}
```

sample Spock Test

```
def "Unit Test"(){
    given:
       //ToDo
    when:
       sampleService.sampleMethodName() //How to access the 'sampleProperty'
    then:
       //ToDo
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spock and groovy test you can access private variables by the variable name at any place

```
def "Unit Test"(){
given:
   sampleService.sampleProperty = "value"  //to set the value
   //ToDo
when:
   sampleService.sampleMethodName() //How to access the 'sampleProperty'
then:
   //ToDo
   sampleService.sampleProperty == "value" //to access the value
}
```